# I want to store the value of my variable in session storage so that it stays when the page

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to store the updated value from the if statement of the variable red, But on refreshing the page the value is still 10. Please suggest any changes I shoulld make.

```
var red = 10;
let blue = 10;
let sblue = 10;
let green = 10;
let yellow = 10;
let add1 = function () {
    var r = document.getElementById("q1").value;
    if (r <= red) {
        red = red - r;
        localStorage.setItem("RKey", red);
        alert("No of Red Space added: " +r) ;
    }
    else {
      alert("Red space out of stock.")
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you **reading** the value you wrote?

Comment: N.B. your question title says "session storage" but your code uses local storage. They're not the same thing, just so you're aware.

Comment: Anyway the value is still 10 because you never attempt to check whether a value already exists in the local storage, and then use that value instead of the default. I'm not really sure why you expected it to change without doing that step.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the value from local storage.

```
var red = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("RKey") || 10);
```